# Is it acceptable to set 'Content-disposition' without 'Content-Length'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have a simple Express.js route:

```
app.get('/db/csv', function (req, res) {
    db.users.find({}, { _id: 0 }, function (err, docs) {
        var csv = /* compute from docs */;

        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=users.csv');
        res.send(csv);
    });
});
```

I use this route to download a CSV version of my "users" database. Setting the `Content-disposition` HTTP response header will trigger the "Save as…" dialog in the browser.

Should I also set a `Content-Length` header? I've seen it in an example and I'm not sure if it's required here. If it's required, how would I calculate the size value from the `csv` variable (which is a JavaScript string)?

(Btw, the functionality in the browser works without `Content-Length`.)

Comment: To calculate byte-length of a string use: `Buffer.byteLength(sData, [sEncoding])`. `sEndcoding` defaults to utf-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not required, it's perfectly fine to set just `Content-Disposition`. For instance, there's nothing in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) or [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) requiring you combine them.

> If it's required, how would I calculate the size value from the csv variable (which is a JavaScript string)?

It isn't, but that doesn't mean it's not nice to include. :-) I haven't done this with NodeJS, but I'd say convert it to a buffer with the appropriate encoding (e.g., the encoding you're including in `charset`) and get the size of the buffer in bytes. Since you're then going to send that buffer as the content, and the buffer's told you how big it is, that should be accurate.

Comment: I guess without the Content-Length, the browser won't be able to provide the download progress (percentage), so it makes sense to set it for huge files.

Comment: Yeah. If you *can* provide it, that's great. I've added a note with thoughts on that.

Comment: Ah btw, RFC 2616 has just been superseded by a bunch of other specs :) https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead

Comment: Interesting! And here I made a point of noting whether it said it was superceded. :-) (It doesn't, in that link above...) Looks like there's an RFC specifically for `Content-Disposition`, though, as of 2011; I've linked it above.

Answer (score 1):

Content-Length and Content-Disposition are orthogonal.

If you don't send Content-Length, you'll have to use Transfer-Encoding chunked. (Usually, your HTTP library will do this for you)